# Changing the color of the tomb. How do I do this?

Tags: html, css

```
<span class="my-icon">
    Club Members
</span>
```

CSS :

```
.my-icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10em;
    height: 6em;
    border: .5em solid blue;
    top: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.my-icon::before {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2em solid #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
    border-top-left-radius: 2em;
    left: 3em;
    top: -2em;
    content:'';
    z-index: 3;
}
.my-icon::after {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2.5em solid blue;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 2.5em;
    border-top-left-radius: 2.5em;
    left: 2.5em;
    top: -2.5em;
    content:'';
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This is the output of what I will get :

[image]

[***jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/577tqu62/) of the above html.

I want to paint the tomb *(the semi-circle above)* red. How do I do this ?

Comment: You'd need a separate element to fill with red. you can't "partially" paint a dom element. it's not a `<canvas>`

Comment: do you want to fill with red or either you want the stroke to be red

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/577tqu62/4/?

Comment: @Benjamin I want to fill it red, just to know why default background is white

Comment: What do you mean? Just changing the border color? http://jsfiddle.net/577tqu62/5/

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/577tqu62/6/?

Comment: Change the `border` of your `before pseudo element` `border: 2em solid red;` It will work

Comment: @j08691 I want to make semi-circle transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `border` property in `.my-icon::before` to : `border: 2em solid red;`

Answer (score 1):

```
.my-icon::before {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2em solid **red**;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
    border-top-left-radius: 2em;
    left: 3em;
    top: -2em;
    content:'';
    z-index: 3;
}
```

That's all.